# SQL Relative Count

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like the following:

| SearchID | Filter | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Type | ... |
| 1 | Value | ... |
| 1 | Origin | ... |
| 2 | Type | ... |
| 2 | Value | ... |
| 2 | Origin | ... |
| 3 | Type | ... |
| 4 | Type | ... |
| 4 | Value | ... |

I want to relatively count how often a certain filter was used by all users.

The expected result would be:

| Ratio | Filter |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Type |
| 0.75 | Value |
| 0.5 | Origin |

I know I could do something like:

```
select count(*) / max(total)
from mytable
join (select count(distinct SearchID) total from mytable) on 1=1
group by Filter
```

but that is not very efficient. My guess is that I could do something with `count(*) over (partition by ...)` but I am not sure how exactly.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.: I am using snowflake but I could easily change that if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assign the total counts to a variable and use that as a denominator

```
set all_search_ids=(select count(distinct search_id) from mytable);

select filter, 
       count(distinct search_id)/$all_search_ids
from mytable
group by filter;
```

But if you really want to use `windows functions`, here's one way

```
select distinct 
       filter, 
       count(distinct search_id) over (partition by filter)/count(distinct search_id) over()
from mytable;
```

Note: The reason I didn't use the `max(total)` is because it would only work if a given filter was used in all the search queries

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
with s as (select filter, count(*) as cnt from t group by filter)
select filter, cnt / max(cnt) over() as ratio from s
```

Comment: It would work in this case, but only if there is a value in `Filter` that has been used in every search. Else the ratio is calculated on the wrong denominator.